# Implementing regional specific fields in Entities in Java project

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

In my project, there is a need to add regional specific fields in whichever entity required. These fields will be visible when the project is run in the particular region. I guess this could be done either by using profiles in `pom.xml` OR by using `web.xml`.

For example :

Employee has name, salary, age. There would be an additional field '`regionalAge`' which would hold age in terms of `Hijri calendar`.

Considering that we enter these details manually on a `jsp`, I want to show the regional specific fields only when required.

I want to implement this by using `Aspect Oriented Programming`. The current implementation is not very developer-friendly. Any suggestions?

P.S. I am new to `AOP` and hope to learn the same via this example.

Q) How has this been presently implemented?

A) A new entity has been created say : RegionalData. This entity has a limited number of fields which are numbered like regionalField1, 2 and so on. This entity needs to be embedded into whichever entity that requires regional specific fields inside of it. Persisting the same has been handled.

There is an xml file say : regionalSpecificMapping.xml in which the 'jspName' in which I wish to use it in and the 'source entity name' are mapped. 
There also is a regional mapping table that does the same and maps name of the field to source entity name and to the regional Field number #1/2/3.

This results in creation a limited number of columns that are created in the table of the entity in which we embedded the RegionalData. In these columns, regional specific values are stored.

I am looking for another approach as the current one will at some point fail to include more fields and would have to include more fields again.

Answer (score 0):

The *first* and the simplest approach is having all regional fields in your class but making them nullable. For example `Employee` class will have "regionalAge" but it will be initialized only if it is relevant for current region. In you presentation layer (jsp) you should show only fields that are not null.

As a variant of this solution you can use `Optional` either from java 8 (if you are using java 8) or guava (if you still in previous version).

*Second solution* is to use base `Employee` class and extend it for specific regions. `Employee` is implemented and packaged into your core project. But you can implement several extensions that provide their own classes that extend `Employee` and add their fields. You can also define factory that creates entities and re-define this factory in each sub-project, so instantiation of your entities could be done using generic way.

Comment: 1. In the first approach, you said that any null field of the 'commandName' should not be shown. How will I accept values for that field because at the beginning, its value would be null. I have not used Optional as my project is on Java 8.

2. I think that the second approach will disrupt the generic-ness of the structure as the whole project is already designed.

Comment: First approach is simple and indeed has its disadvantages. Optional can be used with java 7 if you use guava. The second approach does not break any project. It just requires from your core project to define mechanism of extandable entity factory.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong : I need to create a factory class that provides me objects of either Employee or EmployeeRegional (Which extends Employee and has additional regional specific fields). This object once I receive can now be passed to the 'jsp' in the presentation layer as a command name. In the 'jsp' too, I shall need to show the fields for inputting the regional data based on some condition. Am I right?